# Spring boot filter called twice or not called at all

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented a customFilter that adds something from the request`s cookies to its headers :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        .... some logic...
        log.info("Sending request to next chain for validation..");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        log.info("Authentication completed sucessfully");
    }

    @Bean
    // This method is needed to replace the default cookieFilter.json processor of tomcat that ignores the jwt cookieFilter.json
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
        return tomcatServletWebServerFactory -> tomcatServletWebServerFactory.addContextCustomizers((TomcatContextCustomizer) context -> {
            context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor());
        });
    }

}
```

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class :

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        //configuring strategy
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().and();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(new MyCustomFilter (), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthExceptionEntryPoint());
    }

}
```

When I run the code and send a request via postman/curl I see that the filter triggered twice in the

```
Sending request to next chain for validation..
Sending request to next chain for validation..
Authentication completed sucessfully
Authentication completed sucessfully
```

I found a few posts about issue and I tried the following solutions :

1. It happens because spring registers the beans automatically and I add the filter manually in the configure method. Therefore, I removed the manually addition of the filter in the configure() method. The result was that the filter wasnt called at all.
2. Instead of implementing the filter interface, try to extend the `OncePerRequestFilter` class. Done that, but the filter still triggered twice.
3. Tried also to remove the `@Component` annotation and add the filter manually. In addition I had to move the `CookieProcessor` bean to the Configuration class. The problem that raised afterwards is that the app fails to start because of the following error :

   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

I am using spring-security version 5.3.3.

Comment: Remove `@Component`. It currently is part of the normal filter chain AND the security filter chain, hence it is executed twice (it is also registered twice). The `@Bean` method should be on an `@Configuration` class not this `@Component`.

Comment: I moved the bean to the configuration and I get the following error : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Comment: Return a `TomcatContextCustomizer` and don't add it. You are making things overly complicated.

Comment: I used the following code and I'm still getting the same error :        public TomcatContextCustomizer  cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
        return context -> context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor());
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, don't add `@Bean` methods to `@Component` classes as those are handled differently than those in `@Configuration` classes. (See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts)).

The your code in the `@Bean` is too complex. Create and return a `TomcatContextCustomizer` to do the modification. Your code will lead to circulair references which will lead to initializing errors.

Add the following `@Bean` method to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class

```java
@Bean
public TomactContextCustomizer cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
  return (context) -> context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor());
}
```

Now in your `Filter` either remove the `@Component` **or** add an accompying `FilterRegistrationBean` to prevent it from being added to the regular chain of filters. (Spring Boot automatically registers all detected `Filter` instances to the regular filter chain).

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilterRegistrationBean(MyFilter myFilter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> frb = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(myFilter);
  frb.setEnabled(false);
  return frb;
}
```

If you remove `@Component` the above snippet isn't needed if you don't then you should reuse the scanned `MyFilter` instance in your security configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyFilter myFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        //configuring strategy
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().and();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(myFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthExceptionEntryPoint());
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the clear explanation. I removed the @Component annotation and therefore instead of passing an injected bean I just created a new instance of my filter that I pass to addFilterBefore(..). I tried to run it, but I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: You also need the `TomcatContextCustomizer` else the `LegacyCookieProcessor` won't be registered.

Comment: I didnt write it but I added TomactContextCustomizer  Bean to my @Configuraiton class

Comment: When I run the code without the tomcatContextCustomizer method the spring app starts but my cookies are ignored. With the @Bean method of the customizer, the spring app doesnt start because of the context error I mentioned earlier

Comment: The solution was moving the TomcatContextCustomizer  to a different @Configuration class and not keep it in the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.  Thanks for all the help !!

Comment: You generally want to put it in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, I'll remove the `@Configuration` class remark from the answer.

Comment: In my case I didnt have @SpringbootApplication annotation because this was a submodule that I import into other modules. This submodule responsible for the security authentication and I didnt want to create the tomcat context in each module that imports this sub module. Thanks for all the help again :)