# How to execute a filter or handler only once after successful SAML2 login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml

I am using Spring Security with SAML2 service provider and have a requirement to set custom tokens as part of cookies in the response after a successful SAML2 login.I have created a filter SetToken and configure to call after Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter. The filter is  getting called every time, whereas our requirement is to set custom cookie once after the SAML2 login is successful.

Here is my Spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SAMLConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    SetToken token;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();

        Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/saml2/service-provider-metadata/**")
                .permitAll()
        ).addFilterAfter(token, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(refresh, SecurityContextHolderFilter.class)
        .saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2
                .authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider))
                .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository)
        ).saml2Logout(withDefaults());
    }
}
```

The SetToken filter, which is supposed to be called after SAML2 authorization, is defined as follows, this class is getting called every time which we do not want as token setting happens only once.

```
@Component
public class SetToken extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get principle and make an API call to a third-party system to set the cookie
        // SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        response.addCookie(customCookie);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I also tried setting the session authentication strategy in the configuration, but it is also getting invoked in every request after a successful SAML2 login. We want to attach a handler that is only invoked once after a successful SAML2 login.

```
http.sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(tokenStrategy);
```

The TokenStrategy class implements SessionAuthenticationStrategy and is defined as follows:

```
public class TokenStrategy implements SessionAuthenticationStrategy {

    @Override
    public void onAuthentication(
            Authentication authentication,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws SessionAuthenticationException {
        // Custom logic to get the cookie
        response.addCookie(customCookie);
    }
}
```

**How can I attach a one-time event listener that is executed only after a successful SAML2 login?** Is there a way to have a filter that is only called after the SAML2 filter successfully logs in and is not invoked in any other api/url calls?

Comment: You have fallen into the trap to register your filter as Spring managed bean. When Spring Boot detects a `Filter` in your application context it will automatically register this in the filter chain. As it is also part of the Sprng Security filter chain it will be invoked twice. To fix add a `FilterRegistrationBean` to disable the automatic registration of this bean by Spring Boot.

Comment: Do I need to register filter using ‘ FilterRegistrationBean’ ? How do I can make sure it’s only called once after successful saml2 login ?

Comment: No you need to add a `FilterRegistrationBean` so that you can disable the automatic registration by Spring Boot and as such it is only part of the security chain. Else it will always execute **before** the securiry filter chain. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.embedded-container.servlets-filters-listeners.beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.embedded-container.servlets-filters-listeners.beans) Spring Boot will automatically register any `Filter`, `Servlet` etc. with the servlet container. When this happens the `Filter` will be registered twice (it executes once because it extends `OncePerRequestFilter`!) once as part of the regular chain and next to the embedded Spring Security Filter Chain.

As the regular chain always executes before the embedded Spring Security one it will thus always execute before that.

To prevent the registration add a `FilterRegistrationBean` to tell Spring Boot to ignore this filter for registration. In short set `enabled` to `false`.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<SetToken> setTokenRegistrationBean(SetToken filter) {
  var registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
  registration.setEnabled(false);
  return registration;
}
```

This will prevent Spring Boot from automatically adding it to the normal filter chain. It will now execute only as part of the security chain. Assuming that your SAML filter throws an exception of some sort instead of proceeding the filter chain this should now only execute after authentication.

Duplicate/Similar answers/questions

- [What is implication of adding @Component to custom Spring Security filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381191/what-is-implication-of-adding-component-to-custom-spring-security-filter)
- [Spring boot filter called twice or not called at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241555/spring-boot-filter-called-twice-or-not-called-at-all)
- [Adding a custom filter to be invoked after spring-security filter in a Servlet 3+ environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364436/adding-a-custom-filter-to-be-invoked-after-spring-security-filter-in-a-servlet-3)

Comment: DOn't add code as comments those are totally unreadable!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sumeetpri/4f65308ec1e7464be07160cd9f4f0448

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sumeetpri/67adf959eff2747d70e5b74bef6feb54#file-samlconfiguration-java-L57

Comment: Sorry links without context doesn't really help. What is it you are trying to state?

Comment: I made the change as suggested by you but still I find its getting called in every request and not after Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter chain . Am i missing anything ? You can view my filter and configuration changes in above two link

Comment: Of course it will be invoked before every request as that is the nature of filters. If you want to skip you need to add logic to your filter (like check if the token is already present). Also a filter doesn't feels like the right approach for executing after a SAML redirect.

Comment: How do I can add custom logic to add cookies after sussessful saml login ? The cookie value I need to fetch via api call and set after successful login .

Comment: The approach I thought is via filter because upon successful login it calls filter Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.  I am looking for handler of filter that need to called just once after login.

Comment: I am referring to spring saml guide at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html

Comment: It doesn't call that filter, the filter is called to start/handle the authentication process. The logic of all that is in the filter. If it is not a specific URL (or the request doesn't contain specific information) it just skips and proceeds with the chain for the next filter. THat is simply how servlet filters work, yours isn't any different. BUt still it feels like the wrong place to handle this.

Comment: I also feel that filter is not correct place to handle that . I also tried specific SessionAuthenticationStrategy class . As you can see in the above post example . But that’s also getting called in every request even authentication object is available in spring security context . Is there any better approach to solve this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254071/discussion-between-sumeet-kumar-yadav-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Writing an `AuthenticationSuccesListener` should work, which will be invoked after succesful authentication. Also the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` isn't the right place either that serves a totally different purpose.